# Grid layout using Bootstrap 3.0

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to create a grid layout using Bootstrap 3.0 with white space between columns. I'm using a row and 4 cols with a width of 3. However, all of them appear together without any space in between. How could I do this?

Example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3" style="background-color: grey;">
    col1
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3" style="background-color: grey;">
    col2
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3" style="background-color: grey;">
    col3
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3" style="background-color: grey;">
    col4
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you read [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)?

Comment: See my comment to the answer, I've already quoted the same link. It doesn't say nothing about how to leave space between columns. If you use margin, then there is width overflow

Comment: Considering I posted the link 2 minutes before you pretty much puts you in a weird place, isn't it? Moreover, you don't follow the code mentioned there. Try `col-md-*`

Comment: @ShaharGalukman keep calm, I didn't mean to offend you! I hadn't seen your comment. And if you read the docs, you'll see that what I'm asking is not explained there.

Comment: I'm not offended mate, and for a solution for your issue you can add a class with margin to the right or overriding the class you use from the bootstrap to achieve what you wish for. I'm not sure if Bootstrap3 includes margin in their grid system.

Comment: @ShaharGalukman OK :) Well, using `col-md-*` or `col-lg-*` has no difference here if you're using a large desktop. I'm not a designer and I thought there must be a "more elegant way" to do this.

Comment: It doesn't seems like Bootstrap can provide for a solution, it just lets you have a flexible grid layout, I would go with the margin solution and make sure to use `border-box` so the grid will not break. good luck

Comment: @ShaharGalukman I've just posted an answer that solves the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a discussion with @ShaharGalukman, it seems that Bootstrap 3.0 does not support this feature natively. So, what I did is:

Create the grid using Bootstrap 3.0 syntax with all the columns together. Then, instead of setting the background color to the `col` divs, I created a new `div` inside each `col` that contains the `background-color` setting. This way you have the divisions between columns. You can adjust the white space with the `margin` of the new div. Setting a `margin: -15px` leaves no space between columns.

Hope this helps someone else!

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div style="background-color: grey;">
      col1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div style="background-color: grey;">
      col2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div style="background-color: grey;">
      col3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div style="background-color: grey;">
      col4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have never used or heard of the boostrap class "col-lg-3". I use "spanX" where X is the number of columns in the 12-column grid.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span3" style="background-color: grey;">
    col1
  </div>
  <div class="span3" style="background-color: grey;">
    col2
  </div>
  <div class="span3" style="background-color: grey;">
    col3
  </div>
  <div class="span3" style="background-color: grey;">
    col4
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: BS 3.0 uses a completely different naming system for the grid classes.

Comment: Using `span` is the syntax for Bootstrap 2, the new version 3 uses a different syntax see http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid